# How can I make Vim open help in a vertical split?

Tags: vim-windows, help-system

I usually work in a drop-down terminal, running about 25 characters high. Since I prefer tabs to windows<sup>1</sup>, usually a lot of horizontal space is wasted - around half of the terminal width.

On top of that, Vim, with the default setting of `helpheight`, leaves just about a couple of lines of the file content when I open a help window:

[image]

Is there a way to make `:h` use a vertical split?

I could:

- decrease `helpheight`
- use `<C-W>L` to manually move the window
- make a map or a custom command which does the above for me.

Is there a simpler way?

<sup><sup>1</sup>I *do* use windows when I need to look at multiple files together. But usually I prefer each file to be in its own (mental) context.</sup>

Comment: @statox sorry about that. Dunno what I was thinking when I wrote that.

Comment: Ahah no need to be sorry it also happens to the best ones ;-)

Comment: The same question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630884/opening-vim-help-in-a-vertical-split-window

Comment: It is sometimes even better to use `:tab help` So that current layout is not affected

Answer (score 26):

You can use `:vert h [your topic]` to open help vertically.

You can use the following command:

```
cnoreabbrev H vert h
```

To make vim replace `H` by `vert h` automatically in command line.

Also you can use this abbreviation:

```
cnoreabbrev HR vert bo h
```

To open the help window on the right side of the screen. (see [`:h :botright`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:botright) for more details on `bo`)

Comment: So, no configurable option? Something like `splitright` for `:help`?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean, you'd prefer to be able to choose where the help window should be placed?

Comment: I think you meant `:rightbelow` instead of `:botright`.

Comment: Well it depends on the behavior you are expecting, let says that you should play with `:lefta[bove]`, `:rightb[elow]`, `:to[pleft]` and `:bo[tright]` and see which one you prefer. I prefer `:botright` over `:rightbelow` because what ever my layout is, I'll get a help windows of the full height of the screen. With `:rightbelow` is I already have an horizontal split my help window will be of the height of this split.

Comment: Sadly, writing correct `cabbrev` commands involves some [ritual](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_builtin_command_using_cabbrev).

Answer (score 9):

This is inspired from [junegunn 's *vimrc*](https://github.com/junegunn/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc#L1556):

```
augroup vimrc_help
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter *.txt if &buftype == 'help' | wincmd L | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: I'm curious: how does this differ from `autocmd FileType help wincmd L`? Any edge cases?

Comment: I think that gets triggered twice, at least sometimes (try adding an echo there). It might be something to do with the help window opening, than going to the specific help tag. So, the `BufEnter` would be slightly more efficient. Not to mention adding a command that, when triggered twice, would become "undone" (cancel itself).

Comment: works fine, if you prefer to open on the left side use .. `wincmd H` .

Answer (score 7):

You can use a custom command that does the vertical-or-not selection for you. This can be based on the current window width and height :

```
function! s:ShowHelp(tag) abort
  if winheight('%') < winwidth('%')
    execute 'vertical help '.a:tag
  else
    execute 'help '.a:tag
  endif
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 H call s:ShowHelp(<f-args>)
```

References :

- `:h winheight`
- `:h <f-args>`

Comment: Excellent. This will be very useful for the times I have gvim open covering a vertical half of my screen.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an autocmd in lua for neovim.

```lua
-- Open help window in a vertical split to the right.
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWinEnter", {
    group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("help_window_right", {}),
    pattern = { "*.txt" },
    callback = function()
        if vim.o.filetype == 'help' then vim.cmd.wincmd("L") end
    end
})
```

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a vertical split per-se, I find having help in its own tab to be very nice.

```
augroup HelpInTabs
autocmd!
   autocmd BufEnter *.txt call HelpInNewTab()
augroup END
```

Whoops. I thought I had pasted the whole answer. Here's the rest of the code.

```
" only apply to help files...
function! HelpInNewTab ()
  if &buftype == 'help'
    " convert help window to a tab
    execute "normal \<C-W>T"
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: That would be a good idea to also show what is your `HelpInNewTab()` function because I think this isn't a built-in feature so we can't really test your solution.

Comment: " only apply to help files...
    function! HelpInNewTab ()
      if &buftype == 'help'
        " convert help window to a tab
        execute "normal \<C-W>T"
      endif
    endfunction