# How do I get the actual height and width of Vim?

Tags: vim-windows, window-management

`winheight()` and `winwidth()` return the number of columns/lines in the current window. What I'm looking for is something closer to the actual height and width of the editing area, or displayed area if run in a terminal. The problem with `winheight()` and `winwidth()` is that aspect ratio calculated from these values is out of touch with the actual aspect ratio.

```
:echo winwidth('%') winheight('%') winwidth('%') * 1.0 / winheight('%')
104 51 2.039216
```

A screenshot of the buffer area is sized 936x918 pixels, giving a displayed aspect ratio of `1.019608`. I think I can get the actual value by using the size of the font, but how?

This is a follow-up to [How can I make Vim open help in a vertical split?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/how-can-i-make-vim-open-help-in-a-vertical-split). I'm trying to adapt [Nobe4's solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4472/205).

Comment: I don't think you can get dimensions in pixels with plain Vim functions.  As for opening help in a vertical split, I don't bother with aspect ratio calculations, I just split vertically if the terminal window is wide enough: `cnoreabbrev h <C-r>=(&columns >= 160 && getcmdtype() ==# ':' && getcmdpos() == 1 ? 'vertical botright help' : 'h')<CR>`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura thus following the tradition set by most web developers, who use the document width to determine if it's a mobile. :(

Comment: Not really, since I'm only inflicting that to myself.  I played with aspect ratio for a while and I found the results to be unsatisfactory.  Then I remembered I have exactly two shortcuts for opening terminals, for "normal" size, and for "wide" terminals.  So my terminals almost always have the same sizes.  YMMV of course.

Comment: @SatoKatsura that command is some serious dark magic. I am very surprised that aside from not knowing about the `==#` operator which `:h` helped clear up I actually understood the entire freaking command. Does that make me a Vim expert? Gotta be something like that. Need to get out more.

Answer (score 1):

> 104 columns / 51 lines = 2.04

Your calculation is skewed because the aspect ratio of each cell is vertical.

For example on Terminal.app, with 23pt font and default character spacing, each terminal cell have a width of 7px and a height of 15px for a total of [728x765px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uAat.png):

[image: (104 * 7) / (51 * 15) = 728 / 765 = 0.95]

---

You cannot retrieve the font size from within Vim without invoking external commands or a way of communicating with the terminal, which can become pretty heavy. Obviously, this is different in Gvim thanks to [`'guifont'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27guifont%27).

If you manage to do it, still you need a way to deduct the size of a cell which may vary depending on the terminal program if there is no *standard*. I only checked iTerm 2 which luckily have the same result.

---

Therefore I would opt for a static solution.
I grafted the minimum width check to this snippet you could place in `plugin/help.vim`:

```
function! Help(...)
  let l:topic = a:0 ? a:1 : ''
  if winwidth('%') >= 160 " Minimum width
    execute 'vertical botright help' l:topic
    execute 'vertical resize 78'
  else
    execute 'botright help' l:topic
  endif
endfunction

" Use :H to open a vertical or horizontal help split
command! -complete=help -nargs=? H call Help(<f-args>)
```

If the window is large enough to keep 80 columns of the current buffer, a narrow help split is opened on the right, otherwise the split is opened below. You can customize the split direction with [`:vertical`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Avertical).