# how to remap help command to vert help?

Tags: vimrc

I dislike the default way vim open the help window. I just want to open the help window vertically.

So I want to remap the `help` command to `vert help`.

What I put in vimrc is:

```
:noremap h vert h
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_builtin_command_using_cabbrev, also http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4452/205

Comment: garyjohn answered your question perfectly but thought I'd add a more general 'no, not horizontal, vertical' mapping. `map <leader>v <C-W><S-L>` I use it often, including for `:h`.

Answer (score 4):

The mapping you defined works in normal, visual and operator-pending modes and does not automatically change modes. That is, when you type `h`, you effectively send to Vim the key sequence `vert h`, which enters visual mode (`v`), selects to the end of the current word (`e`), and replaces the visually-selected region (`r`) with the character `t`. Then, back in normal mode, the cursor is moved one position to the right () and one position to the left (`h`).

The mapping you want is this:

```
:nnoremap h :vert h<CR>
```

The colon (`:`) is a necessary part of the `:vert` command, putting Vim into ex mode before accepting the command. The `<CR>` terminates the command as you would if you had typed it.

I used `:nnoremap` rather than `:noremap` because it didn't seem useful to have this mapping work in any but the normal mode.

Answer (score 2):

simply use `cabbrev`:

```
:cabbrev h vert h
```

when type `:h`, it will automatically expand to `:vert h`

Comment: There is a caveat with the solution, and that is any time you press `h` and then `<space>`, it will be expanded to "vert h".

Comment: it will only expand when I type in the command: `h_`,  but it won't expand if type some other command which contain an h like: `xxxh_`, so it's perfect for my problem.

Comment: `:cabbrev help vert help` seems cleaner